# How to add reaction to a specific message using the ID? (discord.py)

Tags: bots

I've been trying for hours a command that react to a message using the ID.
If someone writes !react (the message ID) the bot reacts to the message.
Can someone help me? I have no clue how to do this.

Answer (score 1):

Use a `converter` to get the `discord.Message` instance of the message:

```py
@client.command()
async def react(ctx, message: discord.Message):
    ...
```

Then use [`Message.add_reaction`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=add_reaction#discord.Message.add_reaction) to add a reaction to it, which I'm sure you can figure out by yourself.

Keep in mind that in case the message ID is invalid, can't be found, or is not in the same channel as where the command gets called, the converter will fail & throw you an exception. If you pass in the message's `URL` instead of the ID, Discord will be able to figure out what channel the message was sent in so you can call the command from wherever you want.

You can get a message's URL by selecting `Copy Message Link`, which might be better for your users as getting the `id` requires Developer Mode to be on, which most people don't have enabled. The `MessageConverter` mentioned in the beginning can parse both `id`'s and `URL`'s so you don't have to worry about that part.